# mod-wsgi uses wrong version of python

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to setup Django site with Apache and mod WSGI.
When opening some pages on admin site I get an error

> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

Some more details from error screen:

```
Django Version:     1.7.1
Exception Type:     UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location:     /var/www/.virtualenvs/tankienv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 87
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

Seems that mod-wsgi uses python 2.7 instead of python 3. 
How should I solve this?

When I try to add path to correct python executable to apache2.conf

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/bin
```

site stops responding.

Comment: it IS taking python3.4 (see exception location). the problem is with your encodings, not with python version

Comment: No, it was taking only additional libraries from there. And used Python 2.7. (Sorry, I have skipped this line from error screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of mod-wsgi for python3 should be installed.

I have run these commands to correct this in my Ubuntu 13.04

```
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```